# how to get duplicate records from self join with CTE

Tags: sql

```
Table t1
rule_id 
1
2
3
3
Table t2
rule_id     status      record_seq
1           approve       2
1           pending       1
2           approve       2
2           pending       1
```

Tried as below

```
select * from t1,t2 where t1.rule_id=t2.rule_id and record_seq=2;
rule_id   rule_id       status      record_seq
1           1           approve     2
2           2            approve    2
```

Here record_seq will update once the status will change from pending to approve. But record_seq not like static so by taking and condition on record_seq is wrong according to my assumption.

So please suggest me another way where i can get status as approve only with Join condition or any other logic.

Comment: PLease provide Table Structure And Table Data

Comment: `MySQL <> SQL Server`. Tag the correct RDBMS and ONLY the correct RDBMS.

Comment: I posted table with data also

Comment: Also, stop living in the 1980's! It's 2018! [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). There is no reason to be using 30 year old syntax..

Comment: You've showed what you tried, and the results it gave, which is good. But what did you want to happen? Giving an example of the result you wanted to get would help.

Comment: with out using that record_seq column I need the output not having duplicate records from UI the record sequence will change according to the status

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * 
from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.rule_id=t2.rule_id )
where t2.record_seq = (select max(record_seq) from t2 t 
                        where t.rule_id = t2.rule_id)
```

Note: I have assumed you want latest record_seq

Answer (score 0):

You seems working with SQL Server, if so then you can use `row_number()` function with `JOIN` :

```
select top (1) with ties t1.rule_id, t2.status, t2.record_seq
from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t1.rule_id = t2.rule_id
order by row_number() over (partition by t1.rule_id order by t2.record_seq desc);
```

However, this doesn't have gurantee to provide `approve` status rules_id. So, you can change the `order by` clause as :

```
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by t1.rule_id 
                            order by (case when t2.status = 'approve' then 0 else 1 end)
                            );
```